Does async/await with a non await function and Task creates a new thread?
I am new to async/await and I can not wrap my head around the thread creation.
My queries are:-

Does async function without await creates a new thread to cater getData() as Main thread will not be blocked?
What is Task as a return type doing here? Does it help with any thread creation?
The result of this code is 1,2,ended,3 (Why is 2 printed before ended?)

Here is my code:
public class Class1
    {
        public async Task getValue()
        {

            Console.WriteLine("1");
            var str = getData();
            Console.WriteLine("ended");
            Console.ReadKey();

        }

        private async Task<string> getData()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("2");
            for (long i = 0; i < 100000000000000; i++)
            {
                continue;
            }

            Console.WriteLine("3");

            return "ss";
        }
}

Some forums said that Task is responsible for State management only and no new threads are being created.
But those questions are still in my head.
Please help

@stuartd if that is the case, why is 2 printing before ended?

I really suggest you read a book about the topic as it is very very complex - C# in a Nutshell, or CLR via C# (even if it's old)

@IvanPetrov well I have been studying a lot about it since 2 days. I am just stumbled upon if Thread is created or not via Task ? I know async await do not participate in any Thread creation or something

async does not create a new thread, in fact your async methods run all on the same thread and it should be printing 1 2 3 ended

a Task in itself just represents an (asynchronous) unit of work, whether this is done on another thread or not is a separate issue.

the output is not as you have suggested. Also Task is a return type here. But what role it plays here is my question

Pay attention to the warning: CS1998 This async method lacks the 'await' operators and will run synchronously....

@Steve that is true, but if it is synchronous, 3 must be printed before ended right?

Yes, it prints 3 before 'ended' as it should

Look at what happens if you add await Task.Delay(1000); just before Console.Writeline("3");

@Steve But by using Task.Delay, it does not stay async right? because "truly async" wants to await while calling thread is free but it will not run the further code and print "ended". If instead of Task.Delay there was a DB call(along with await in both cases), then output will be 1,2,3, ended...... but instead of DB call when we added Task.Delay, the order of output changes to 1,2,ended,3. why?

Related: Does the use of async/await create a new thread?

@Ryan you are not really replying to me, are you?

@Parth async/await is about effective usage of CPU resources, not creating threads...

@Ryan you are describing asynchronous programming, not async/await. These two are not the same thing. Async/await is just a tool that makes asynchronous programming easier. Please avoid making conceptual statements in the comments of a question, because they provoke discussions, which make it difficult to use the comments for their intended purpose. Which is to guide the OP into editing and clarifying/improving their question. You could post an answer instead.

@TheodorZoulias yes, i am about asyncronous programming, because async/await is about it. It is called knowledge generalization, when you are able to describe complex thing in a short and concise manner. OP might grasp the idea, just by wondering a bit deeper what that sentence meant.

@Ryan that's great, but the comments are not the correct place to offer generalized knowledge to the OP. That's what the answers are for. The StackOverflow is a Q/A site, not a forum.

@TheodorZoulias, okay i got your point.

@TheodorZoulias could you please answer me?  Question:   But by using Task.Delay, it does not stay async right? because "truly async" wants to await while calling thread is free but it will not run the further code and print "ended". If instead of Task.Delay there was a DB call(along with await in both cases), then output will be 1,2,3, ended...... but instead of DB call when we added Task.Delay, the order of output changes to 1,2,ended,3. why?   What is Task.Delay doing to make it Fire and Forget but if we do a DB call then it is a normal async await?

@​Parth I have already posted an answer to this question. You can ask for clarifications in the comments under my answer. If you have more questions to ask, probably the correct thing to do is to post a new question.

Marking method as async does not actually makes it magically asynchronous, it still is a synchronous one unless it does something "truly async" (usually it is an awaited call to another "truly async" method). Everything before first await on "truly async" call will be executed synchronously.
Since your method is not actually an async one it will block current thread until it is completed. If you want to return control to the calling method you can add call like await Task.Delay(...):
private async Task<string> getData()
{
    await Task.Delay(1000);
    Console.WriteLine("2");
    // ...
}

Which should result in the expected behavior (i.e. 2 printed after ended).

Does async function without await creates a new thread to cater getData() as Main thread will not be blocked?

No, it does not.

What is Task as a return type doing here? Does it help with any thread creation?

It allows caller to await the getData call when needed. Task is basically a future/promise which represents a result of some computation which can finish in the future.
I highly recommend to read about the topic more:

Asynchronous programming doc
Asynchronous Programming in .NET - Introduction, Misconceptions, and Problems
There Is No Thread


But in what condition it will become "FIRE AND FORGET" ? I have made these 2 functions as Async and without await.. It should fire the getData method and move on with the main thread to execute getValue() ?

@Parth it will become fire-and-forget if you will add await Task.Delay or wrap contents in Task.Run call.

But by using Task.Delay, it does not stay async right? because "truly async" wants to await while calling thread is free but it will not run the further code and print "ended". If instead of Task.Delay there was a DB call(along with await in both cases), then output will be 1,2,3, ended...... but instead of DB call when we added Task.Delay, the order of output changes. why?

@Parth it depends on what do you mean by "stays async". And what db call you are talking about. In modern .NET db calls usually are made in "truly async" fashion (though there can be exceptions).

According to Microsoft's guidelines:

An asynchronous method that is based on TAP can do a small amount of work synchronously, such as validating arguments and initiating the asynchronous operation, before it returns the resulting task. Synchronous work should be kept to the minimum so the asynchronous method can return quickly.

Your getData asynchronous method violates this guideline by doing all the work synchronously, and returning a completed task. This can be easily verified:
Debug.Assert(getData().IsCompleted == true);

And most likely also:
Debug.Assert(getData() == Task.CompletedTask);

Some people would disagree that is OK to call the getData "asynchronous". They would call it synchronous, or fake asynchronous. The terminology that I prefer is that the getData is a method with asynchronous signature and synchronous implementation. To answer your questions directly:

Does async function without await creates a new thread to cater getData() as Main thread will not be blocked?

No, a new thread in not created. All code runs on the main thread of the console application.

What is Task as a return type doing here? Does it help with any thread creation?

The Task represents the completion of the asynchronous method. In case an exception is thrown inside the async method, the information about the exception will be stored inside this Task. Invoking the getData will never throw synchronously the exception. In order to expose the exception, you'll have to Wait or await the resulting Task. The Task doesn't create any thread by itself, no.

Why is 2 printed before ended?

Because all code runs synchronously on the same thread from start to finish.
The purpose of the async/await technology is to enable the composition of derived asynchronous methods that are based on primitive asynchronous methods. For example if you have a built-in asynchronous API like the HttpClient.GetStringAsync, you can easily use it to author an asynchronous method that fetches some information from the internet based on specific parameters, and returns a deserialized representation of the data. The data will be returned on a thread that is decided by the implementation of the primitive API that you are calling. When the Task completes, the await continuation will run on whatever thread was selected by the HttpClient.GetStringAsync implementation. It's not up to you to decide. What the caller of your API can do is to install a specialized SynchronizationContext on the current thread, that will cause a redirection from the thread selected by the HttpClient.GetStringAsync implementation to a thread selected by the SynchronizationContext implementation. Most UI frameworks (WinForms, WPF etc) install automatically their own specialized SynchronizationContext on the UI thread, so the developers don't have to do anything special. You can learn more about this here:

What thread runs the code after the await keyword?

